# How to remove all Telegram group users programmatically with API

Tags: telegram

So I’m trying to start a Telegram group over but before I do, I need to remove all the group members from it. Given there’s too many members to do them one at a time, I’m looking to do this programmatically using api. I’d rather not add a bot to the group to accomplish this, and I don’t want to delete the actual group as everyone already has the link to access it. And yes I obviously have admin privileges. Does anyone know of an easy way to accomplish this using a script via TG API all at once?